# What is a good choice of letters for serial numbers?

Tags: readability

When creating serial numbers, one could use only numbers, `0`-`9`.  This causes serial numbers to be quite long.  To save space, one could also user letters `A`-`Z`, resulting in shorter numbers, by a factor of 1.56 (log 36 / log 10).  But this can cause trouble reading those serial numbers, since `0` and `O` are quite similar.  Also `l` and `1`, and mayby `I` and `1`, or even `J` and `1`.

So a first approximation seems to be to use the digits `0123456789ABCDEFGHKMNPQRSTUVWXYZ` for serial numbers.  That is 32 digits and hence serial numbers are still 1.51 times shorter than in base-10.

Is there any well-known best practice for issuing serial numbers?

Comment: Related: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/134080/passcode-generation-guidelines/134081

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passcode generation guidelines?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/134080/passcode-generation-guidelines) It is asking about passcode generation, but doing so based on the same criteria as you mention; being visually unambiguous, but still retaining great entropy.

Comment: Yes! The mentioned article has all the information I was looking for. Thanks!