# Name for special limited alphabet that doesn't include "look alikes" (o, 0, i, 1, L)

Tags: text

Is there a special limited alphabet that does not include characters which look similar?

I.e., does not include:

```
0 O
i L 1
```

Use case:
This is for assigning a unique user ID. And we don't want them confusing i, l, 1, etc. if they manually type it.

Comment: Related: [Passcode generation guidelines?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/134080/passcode-generation-guidelines)

Comment: I wasn't able to find the name of an alphabet, but the characters are called homoglyphs (also: confusables), in case that's helpful.

Comment: Can you give more detail on where you want to apply this? Then we could help more.

Comment: Also, with this much information, would using "Alpha, Beta, Charlie, Delta, Echo, Foxtrot, Golf...." Military/Phonetic alphabets help you?

Comment: You're just asking about terminology here? Just needing the name of a specific subset of the alphabet that you decide upon? Is this just to facilitate internal communication, or is it something you're trying to communicate to the user somewhere?

Comment: _restricted alphabet_

Comment: Just use a font where they *are* distinguishable; like all monospace fonts (IIRC). But "no-homoglyphs-font" (after Izquierdo comment) is probably unhelpful to most users if this is to be a front-facing terminology.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a widely known/used word for this. A well-known password generator website, [passwordsgenerator.net](https://passwordsgenerator.net) calls the option 'Exclude Similar Characters':

[image]

but more importantly, they give an *example* of what they exclude, so it's immediately clear what they mean.